# reason for requested resource is not available?

Tags: grails, database-migration, changelog

I describe the problem here. I first checkout a grails app from git. It is develop branch. I then delete my local database and create a new empty database/schema naming it test2.

Now, i build the app once so that the necessary tables are created. I now add a new property which is "String testing" to the domain that is already present. The name of the domain where we add the property is AnswerSurvey.groovy.

I now right click on the project and then in grails tools > open grails command prompt. There i type dbm-gorm-diff

then in the console as expected the new changelog lines are shown

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-2.0.xsd">
    <changeSet author="test (generated)" id="1432536391982-1">
        <addColumn tableName="answer_survey">
            <column name="testing" type="varchar(255)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
        </addColumn>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

I convert this to groovy and add it to changelog.groovy file. Now i am ready to push these two files, one the changed domain file and another this changelog file to server. I commit and push these two files to server. The jenkins build is triggered. After the build is complete i access the server url and this error is shown.

[image]

I am wondering what is the reason for this error? please note that in the database this new property "testing" is not present in the answer_survey table. Also, in the config grails.plugin.databasemigration.updateOnStart = true is present. I appreciate any help! I have been stuck on this problem for a while. Thank you!

Comment: please, show RoadraceController

Comment: @Koloritnij i have not made any changes to the controller classes. Before adding the new property "testing" to AnswerSurvey domain the url worked fine. After adding the new property and the changelog then the url doesnt work. It gives "requested resource is not available" as shown above.

Comment: What in logs? If only this page failed, so please show this controller if it possible, and groovy represent of changelog

Comment: groovy representation is changeSet(author:"test (generated)", id:"1432788745862-1"){
   addColumn(tableName:"answer_survey"){
    column(name:"testing", type:"varchar(255)"){
     constraints(nullable:"false")
    }
   }
  }